# MongoDB aggregate query for the messaging app

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am working on an app that has a message function (chat) and I want to get all the users that I have or who have sent me messages and group all these users in the order where the contact with the most communication recent arrives at the top.
and counted all the messages I received from the other user that I haven't read yet.

**Mongo messages Model**

```
const userChat = new Schema({
  senderUserId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  message: {
    type: String
  },
  room: {
    type: Array
  },
  files: {
    type: Array
  },
  read: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
  },
  receiverUserId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})
```

**My MongoDB aggregate**

```
const user = await UserChat.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    $and: [{
      $or: [{
          receiverUserId: req.user._id
        }, // User is in recepients
        {
          senderUserId: req.user._id
        }, // or the sender
      ],
    }, ],
  },
},
{
  $sort: {
    createdAt: -1,
  },
},
{
  // if the message is send by me then i group the "$receiverUserId"
  // if not that mean i am the receiver so i group the "$senderUserId"
  $group: {
    _id: {
      $cond: {
        if: {
          $eq: ["$senderUserId", req.user._id]
        },
        then: "$receiverUserId",
        else: "$senderUserId"
      }
    },
    count: {
      $sum: {
        $cond: ["$read", 0, 1]
      },
    },
    createdAt: {
      $first: "$createdAt",
    },
  },
},

$lookup: {
  from: "users",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "_id",
  as: "user",
},
}, {
$sort: {
  createdAt: -1,
},
}, {
$project: {
  _id: 1,
  count: 1,
  createdAt: 1,
  user: 1,
},
}, ]);
```

### **example of data i want to get**

say for example we have two users writing to each other.
user 1 is called **Papi Johnson** and the other is **Prince Michel**.

**Prince Michel** sends two messages to **Papi johnson**.
as Papi johnson has not yet read Prince Michel's message so when Papi johnson makes a request for the messages he has sent or received, then the result should be:

```
{
_id: 5f8cf7e3c68dd730b5edb8a9, // the ID of Prince Michel
count: 2, // number of message unread send by Prince Michel to Papi johnson
createdAt: 2020-10-19T02:27:39.759Z, // the last message receive
user: [ [Object] ] // in then the user info of Prince Michel 
}
```

and when **Prince Michel** makes a request to have the message he sent or received, then the result should be:

```
{
_id: 5f8cf8f5b76f3e3d5e6e249f,// the ID of Papi johnson
count: 0, // number of message unread send by Papi johnson to Prince Michel  
createdAt: 2020-10-19T02:27:39.759Z,
user: [ [Object] ]// in then the user info of Papi johnson
}
```

### **this is what I receive as a result:**

**example in photo**

[response received on example Papi and Prince](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96ZLl.jpg)

**the problem is that I get the same number of unread messages for both users.
I think the problem may be "$ group" and "$ sum" query does not count only unread message received by the user, but rather all unread message that is sent or received by the user.
it's been more than 10 days since i blogged at this level and i don't know what to really do.
**

when Papi johnson makes a request for the messages he has sent or received, the result is :

```
{
_id: 5f8cf7e3c68dd730b5edb8a9, // the ID of Prince Michel
count: 2, 
// I think here the "$ group" and "$ sum" 
//query does not count only unread message received by the user,
// but rather all unread message that is sent or received by the user.
createdAt: 2020-10-19T02:27:39.759Z, // the last message receive
user: [ [Object] ] // in then the user info of Prince Michel 
}
```

and when **Prince Michel** makes a request to have the message he sent or received,the result is :

```
{
_id: 5f8cf8f5b76f3e3d5e6e249f,// the ID of Papi johnson
count: 2, 
// I think here the "$ group" and "$ sum" 
//query does not count only unread message received by the user,
// but rather all unread message that is sent or received by the user.
createdAt: 2020-10-19T02:27:39.759Z,
user: [ [Object] ]// in then the user info of Papi johnson
}
```

Comment: Can you post what result you are getting now and what you are expecting?

Comment: hello @wak786 i make some update , i hope that answer your question . thanks

Comment: yeah I unsertood the question now.

Comment: can you provide some sample documents so that i can use them to wirte query. You can create `Mongo Playground` and share the link with me. https://mongoplayground.net/

Comment: @wak786 here is the link https://mongoplayground.net/p/jrrlObv--b4

Comment: Thanks!! So you are getting different counts now.

Comment: Check this - https://mongoplayground.net/p/KnrY93VmI22

Comment: Check this for user `5f7a5fbc08d6947f1f26b320`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/v3nhbrxIlk1

Comment: @wak786 he thanks , i already  try this exemple . the problem is it only works if both user receive message from each one.

Comment: if John writes to David and David also writes to John, then the example you set works perfectly. but if John wrote to David and David had never written to John:
then the example will only work for David,

Comment: and for John the answer will be an empty array because the "$ match" only searches for messages where user is the receiver

Comment: @wak786 you can see here https://mongoplayground.net/p/RaAIRqTbW0T

Comment: I think John receiving empty array  should be fine. Because he doesn't have any unread messages. Correct me if I am wrong. Also what do we expect in case of John then?

Comment: @wak786 if John has no unread message then John should have David's info and count = 0